# How to see old job execution result logs from ldf file?

Tags: sql-server

In the Agent job view history of SQL Server, there are just limited log rows of o executed job. I want to see old executed job logs. Is there any way to see that?

Comment: The LDF file is the transaction logs of the database, the majority of which will be details of transactions that occured since the last transaction log backup (assuming you're using a full backup model). You don't use it to get the logs of the SQL Agent; that has it own log file(s).

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks a lot. It was right what I want

Comment: You should have a button above to accept the duplicate, which will close the question and show this link in a banner at the top

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to see that?

Job history is stored in MSDB, so on test server restore an old backup of MSDB.